# Flume Regex Filtering Interceptor is not working as expected

Tags: regex, apache, log4j, flume

I am trying to implement a simple Flume test app, like one from the [Flume User Guide](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#a-simple-example), except that I want to use a log4j as a source and accept the logs that match some regexp.  So I have implemented a random log generator and configured log4j and flume like this:

#### log4j.properties

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, stdout
#
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L -     %m%n
#
log4j.appender.flume = org.apache.flume.clients.log4jappender.Log4jAppender
log4j.appender.flume.Hostname = localhost
log4j.appender.flume.Port = 41414

# configure a class's logger to output to the flume appender
log4j.logger.generator.LogGenerator = INFO,flume

log4j.appender.flume.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.flume.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

#### secondExample.conf

```
# Flume test file
# Listens via Avro RPC on port 41414 and dumps data received to the log

agent.channels = ch-1
agent.sources = src-1
agent.sinks = sink-1

agent.channels.ch-1.type = memory
agent.channels.ch-1.capacity = 10000000
agent.channels.ch-1.transactionCapacity = 1000

agent.sources.src-1.type = avro
agent.sources.src-1.channels = ch-1
agent.sources.src-1.bind = localhost
agent.sources.src-1.port = 41414

agent.sources.src-1.interceptors = intrcptr
agent.sources.src-1.interceptors.intrcptr.type = regex_filter
agent.sources.src-1.interceptors.intrcptr.regex = "ERROR [0-4]:"

agent.sinks.sink-1.type = logger
agent.sinks.sink-1.channel = ch-1
```

#### sample generated logs:

```
2013-11-18 15:27:06 ERROR LogGenerator:33 - ERROR 3: 68290a60-8c25-494d-9d0d-4361a01f065f
2013-11-18 15:27:35 WARN  LogGenerator:33 - ERROR 2: 154c4779-ad6a-4b10-9ba7-199a02ad7554
2013-11-18 15:28:49 WARN  LogGenerator:33 - ERROR 5: a2a94b78-e387-4937-b6b3-c480e2c7ea76
2013-11-18 15:29:35 FATAL LogGenerator:33 - ERROR 6: 49baaa6b-19cb-48c8-9f92-b7a75f8d04dc
```

The problem is that Regex Filtering Interceptor does not exclude any events, and logger sink logs all of the generated log messages. I have found [this source code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/flume/trunk/flume-ng-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/interceptor/RegexFilteringInterceptor.java), and wrote a small test with generated logs and slightly modified *intercept* method (so that it takes and returns Strings, not Events) and it works as expected.

I am really confused right now and tend to think that this is a Flume bug. 
Any help will be appreciated.

**P.S.** I am using "apache-flume-1.4.0-bin" flume.

Comment: is this somehow connected with [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLUME-2041)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a [Flume issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLUME-2249). It is reproducible if Flume is configured like this:

`Log4jAppender -> Avro source -> Regex interceptor -> Logger Sink`

The workaround is to configure Flume with two agents like this:

`Log4jAppender -> Avro source -> Avro sink -> Avro source -> Regex interceptor -> Logger Sink`

Comment: Edited it so that it is no longer a "link-only answer".

Comment: Issue is marked as Not A Problem, it was the log from AvroSource, not a log from LoggerSinker.

Comment: Can you please answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805936/flume-can-an-entire-file-be-considered-an-event-in-flume ? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @CodingInCircles, I am very pleased by that comment of yours, but unfortunately I wasn't working with Flume since the time of this question and I can hardly recall any details about it. Thanks & Sorry.

Comment: That's alright! :) Someone else answered it and gave me the details I needed. Did not mean to hijack the thread or anything :)