# How to use flume for uploading zip files to hdfs sink

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I am new to flume.My flume agent having source as http server,from where it getting zip files(compressed xml files) on regular interval.This zip files are very small (less than 10 mb) and i want to put the zip files extracted into the hdfs sink.Please share some idea how to do this.Do i have to go for a custom interceptor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flume will try to read your files line by line, except if you configure a specific deserializer. A deserializer lets you control how the file is parsed and split into events. You could of course follow the example of the blob deserizalizer, which is designed for PDFs and such, but I understand that you actually want to unpack them and then read them line by line. In that case you would need to write a custom deserializer which reads Zip and writes line by line events.

Here's the reference in the documentation:

https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#event-deserializers

Comment: thanks erik...blob deserizalizer  is the perfect solution for this.few more doubts ...is it efficient to process a file as a single event.Is it possible to set some file name with event.setHeader method.Its asking for a map.can you share something on this.

Comment: Well it*s not very efficient to spool entire files in one event, I would always try to use the deserilizer to parse single events. You can set the file header to preserve the original filename. this is an option in SpoolSource, you can have a look at that in the docs. Please accept my answer if it worked for you.